# How can I order by count in mysql when the count need data to calculate from this select statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Look at my code, I want the select statement order by the count percentage after I fetch the data from this select statement, obviously, it's not logical. What can I do? Help, appreciate.

```html
<?php
   //myslq connection code, remove it because it's not relate to this question


    $stm =$db->prepare("SELECT id ,term_count, COUNT(user_id) as count FROM sign WHERE term IN (:term_0,:term_1) GROUP BY user_id ORDER by count DESC");
   //trying replace order by count with $combine_count, but it's wrong

 $term_0="$term[0]";
 $term_1="$term[1]";
    $stm->bindParam(":term_0", $term_0);
 $stm->bindParam(":term_1", $term_1);
      stm->execute();
     $rows = $stm->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     foreach ($rows as rows) {
     $count=$rows['count'];
     $term_count_number=$rows['term_count'];
     $count_percentage=round(($count/$count_user_diff)*100);
    $count_key_match=round(($count/$term_count_number)*100);
    $combine_count=round(($count_percentage+$count_key_match)/2);
    //issue is here, I want the select statement order by $combine_count
 }



?>
```

Comment: Describe the words that you want to get.
And attach the table schema.

Comment: how to describe the word and attach the table schema?

Comment: table schema:[code] 
    CREATE TABLE `table1` (
     `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `data` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     `a` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
     `b` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
    ENGINE=InnoDB[code]

Comment: Then, where did `user_id` come from?  Wait!?  Is the table `sign` or `table1`??  Please edit the question to have the correct CREATE TABLE and the correct fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  id ,term_count, COUNT(user_id) as `count`
    FROM  sign
    WHERE  term IN (:term_0,:term_1)
    GROUP BY  user_id
    ORDER by  `count` DESC");
```

Since "count" is a function, it would be better to put backtics around the non-function "counts", as done above.

GROUP BY should list the field not aggregated.  Otherwise, it does not know which id and term_count to fetch.  So, depending on what you are looking for,

Either do

```
SELECT  user_id, COUNT(*) as `count`  -- I changed this line
    FROM  sign
    WHERE  term IN (:term_0,:term_1)
    GROUP BY  user_id
    ORDER by  `count` DESC");
```

or do

```
SELECT  id ,term_count, COUNT(*) as `count`
    FROM  sign
    WHERE  term IN (:term_0,:term_1)
    GROUP BY  id ,term_count    -- I changed this line
    ORDER by  `count` DESC");
```

Comment: COUNT(*) is better than COUNT(user_id)?? For what I understand, COUNT(*) count everything,   COUNT(user_id) count user_id, right? so  COUNT(user_id) should be faster and better, right?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` if faster.  `COUNT(col)` checks col for being `NOT NULL`.  `COUNT(DISTINCT col)` counts the number of different values for `col`.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Syntax Logic

```
SELECT column1, count(column1) AS amount
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 12
```